# Bad headphone driver resistance

Tags: audio, resistance, driver, headphones

I have a pair of ATH-M50 headphones where the right side has stopped working. I took them apart and measured the resistance at the L/R terminals on each driver. The good one measures about 35 ohms whereas the bad one is around 200 ohms. Another set of good ATH-M50 measures 35 ohms on both drivers.

Does this make sense for a blown driver? [This guy's](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/142675-replacing-a-blown-ath-m50-driver-walkthrough-with-pics/) bad driver showed an open circuit.

Comment: yes, it makes sense

Comment: Hmm were your ears also blown from melting the coil or vibration friction?  does it Pop with a battery?